# Network says "Bridged" but no bridge exists

Tags: windows, networking, bridge

So I'm having trouble removing a network bridge that doesn't actually exists, here's a screen shot. Anyone have any ideas? http://puu.sh/2lOlB

Comment: What have you tried? Right clicking the icon and un-bridging should be all thats required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screen shot it is evident that the network card is bridged with your wi-fi connection.So you can either place your mouse pointer on your wifi connection and right click on it and then you will get an option to unbridge the connection,click on it to unbridge the connection.If this doesnt work you can try uninstalling the network drivers from the device manager or from the control panel and restart your system once.Best Regards, Joel from http://morningtadka.com - Best Technology blog

Comment: Yeah, there were no options to remove a brige - there was some sort of glitch going on. Anyway, reinstalling the network card drivers did the trick, thanks for your reply.